# How to apply only single rule or set of rules with prettier (or prettierx)

Tags: javascript, formatting, prettier

Would like to use prettier (or prettierx or similar tool) in the following way:

```sh
npx prettier --no-defaults --no-semi --write test.js
```

where `--no-defaults` is a hypothetical option to ignore & not apply any other rules except for those specified (ONLY apply the `--no-semi` rule/option in this case).   In otherwords, I only want to run prettier and apply a single rule or the set of rules I specify.

I read through the docs and seems there is no obvious way to do this; I realize prettierx is supposed to be less opinionated but also does not seem to offer a way to run without applying its own defaults.

Comment: If you are not limited to prettier, eslint can help, it's not opinionated and have most of the rules that prettier provides. [helpful-link](https://itnext.io/how-to-replace-prettier-by-eslint-rules-21574359e041)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ESLint for that purpose, a one-liner approach for the above example would look like this:

```
eslint --fix --rule 'semi: [error, never]' test.js
```

To define multiple rules, separate them using commas, or use the option multiple times. If adding multiple rules it's recommended to add them to a dedicated file like `eslintrc.json` or declare them in `package.json` where they will be automatically parsed by eslint, thus eliminating the need for rule option in command line. More on configuration [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/).

Caution: Providing rules through command line will merge them with existing eslint config if present in your project, in order to avoid that you can add a flag like this:

```
eslint --no-eslintrc --fix --rule 'semi: [error, never]' test.js
```

Most of the layout and formatting rules are fixable by eslint, a comprehensive list is given [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/#layout-formatting). To know more about eslint and other helpful command line flags see [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) and [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface).